# Android Focus : OnAudioFocusChage

Tags: android, audio, onfocuschangelistener

I have seen in many use cases implementations that onAUdioFocusChange only treats Focus_Gain, Focus_Loss, Focus_Loss_transient, Focus_loss_transient can duck , is there a reason to not add Focus_Gain_transient, and focus_gain_transient_may_duck focus changes.

Comment: Can you show me a case that did not handle focus_gain_transient/focus_gain_transient_may_duck?

Answer (score 0):

The issue I encountered pertains to the ICarAudioFocus interface in Android. I observed that the standard implementation of CarAudioFocus.onAudioFocusAbandon tends to dispatch a focus change of type AUDIO_FOCUS_GAIN, irrespective of the specifics detailed in the AudioFocusInfo.

[onAudioFocusAbandn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWNMi.png) [removeBlockerAndRestoreUnblockedFocusLosersLocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWBJ9.png) [dispatchFocusGainedLocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ber5.png)

To illustrate with an example: consider a media player that has gained focus with AUDIO_FOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT and is currently in playback mode. If an emergency announcement occurs, it interrupts the player and takes over the audio focus. Once the announcement is finished and abandonAudioFocus is called, the onAudioFocusAbandon listener gets activated. This is meant to inform the previously interrupted focus holder (in this case, the media player) about the focus change. However, in the default Android Open Source Project (AOSP) implementation of CarAudioFocus, the dispatched focus change is always AUDIO_FOCUS_GAIN, regardless of the actual AudioFocusInfo of the new focus holder.

This means that the default handling within onAudioFocusChange only accounts for the AUDIO_FOCUS_GAIN type of gain. Consequently, the type of implementation used - be it the default AOSP or a specific OEM (Original Equipment Manufacturer) implementation - determines which use cases need to be addressed in the onAudioFocusChangeListener. The choice between these implementations should be based on the specific requirements and nuances of the audio focus management

Comment: Please do not post code or errors as image, use formatted text instead.

Comment: If this is your solution, this is fine, but please clearly state so. If this is an update to your issue, it would be much better to edit and update your question.